# F# find the first occurrence of an even number

Tags: f#

I need a function that returns the first occurrence of an even element. For example:

`let ls= [3;7;8;9;10;5;12;40]
let first_even ....
ls |> first_even // should return 10`

Comment: Hi, please post your current function, and then we can see what is wrong in it. You should always share your current work to receive a help.

Comment: I agree...there are 2 basic approaches though, I suspect this is homework? if youre a beginner youre probably better off doing a recursive function.

Comment: or find an example of something that does something like give you the length of the list and see if you can change it to do what you want.

Comment: first_even should return 8 IMO

Comment: As far as I know 8 is even as well, but maybe something changed :) Seriously now though: please post what you've tried, and where the issue is. SO is a place to look for help understanding things, not homework service.

Comment: Side note: `first_even` is not a function name you'd typically see in F#; the convention here is camel casing, so it should be `firstEven`. It is helpful to have read the [F# Style Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide)  (especially the formatting guidelines) to get a general idea of the conventions typically used.

Answer (score 0):

`let first_even = List.find(fun x -> x%2=0)`

Comment: Even though it probably does what it should, I believe this is not what the OP is looking for :)

Comment: If it's not specified, it's decided by the implementor. Also something one has to learn :-)

Comment: You could've used at least `List.tryFind`. This will throw an exception if there are no even numbers.

Comment: to be fair, I think he needs to be walked through a recursive approach, this answer could be in any language.